# Global variable assigned by reference inside a file included in a function

Tags: php, reference, scope, php-include

Below is a simplified example of how a certain 3rd party module adds a 3rd party application into a page. The application is normally meant to be standalone and accessed directly, but the module uses a function to include the application at a specific URL.

**module.php:**

```
if ($path == 'some/specific/url') {
  load_app();
}

function load_app() {
  include('./app.php');
}
```

**app.php:**

```
// For this example, assume $_SESSION['a'] already exists as an array of strings.

global $b;

$b = &$_SESSION['a'];

do_something();

function do_something() {
  global $b;

  // Do something with $b.

  // Problem: $b is always NULL when it should be an array.
}
```

The problem is that the line `$b = &$_SESSION['a'];` in app.php doesn't seem to work properly so `$GLOBALS['b']` remains NULL which means `$b` is also NULL inside `do_something()`.

This appears to be because app.php is included from within a function in module.php, so I assume it's something to do with the scope of app.php and the assignment by reference.

Unfortunately, I can't modify app.php at all and I can't move the `include()` outside of the `load_app()` function in module.php, so is there any other way that module.php can be altered to make app.php work as it is supposed to?

Comment: You're referencing PHP _SESSION but I don't see any session_start()...

Comment: @marekful The framework running module.php creates a session and so does app.php if accessed directly, but I tried to simplify the example as much as possible. We can assume $_SESSION['a'] always exists as an array for this so I left out all the session code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error with inserting `global $b;` in various places in an effort to propagate the global variable, what finally worked for me was the following:

**module.php:**

```
function load_app() {
  $GLOBALS['b'] = &$_SESSION['a'];
  include('./app.php');
}
```

It seems that assigning the reference directly to `$GLOBALS['b']` in module.php allows app.php to work properly without any modifications. Assigning the reference to `global $b` does not.